# How to install app using PackageInstaller for Profile Owner?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

I am trying to install a apk file using Package Installer. My app is current profile owner. The method is completing successfully but in my BroadcastReceiver I am getting PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION. As per android docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller app should be able to silently install apk if it is a profile owner.

```
     public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream 
   in, 
       String packageName)
        throws IOException {
      final PackageInstaller packageInstaller = 
    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    final PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new 
     PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    final int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    final PackageInstaller.Session session = 
   packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    final OutputStream out = session.openWrite("TestDPC", 0, -1);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    session.fsync(out);
      in.close();
       out.close();

       session.commit(createInstallIntentSender(context, sessionId));
       return true;
    }
```

Comment: Which OS version are you on? I've seen comments that Lollipop will still require user action...

Comment: I have tried on O,P and Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app must be set as device owner or *affiliated* profile owner.